# <td>'s aligned vertically for responsive

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to align `<td>`s in a `<tr>` such that each `<td>` is on top of one another. I am looking for a responsive workout for a table which cannot be changed to `<ul>-<li>`. So for example I have a table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
```

Here 1,2 and 3 should come like:

```
1
2
3
```

not

```
1  2  3.
```

I have tried `display:block,` `display:flex`, `clear: both` and `float: none` but no effect. Please let me if know there is a way to do it.

Comment: What does the rest of your table look like? [display:block on the cell works fine](http://jsbin.com/wilax/1/edit)

Comment: What exactly did you try (full CSS code)?

Comment: The main problem with such styling is that IE 9 and older do not let you change the display style of table-related elements. So it is crucial whether the approach needs to cover such browsers. If it does, you should look for JavaScript approaches.

Answer (score 1):

in case of table we are not able to break it as td to tr from the css or dependends on nay screen size.

for you case
you have to use css table.

like

```
<div id="table">
  <div calss="table-cell">1<div>
  <div calss="table-cell">2<div>
  <div calss="table-cell">3<div>
</div>
```

css

```
#table{
    display:table;
}
#table div{
    display:table-cell;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  #table{
      display:block;
  }
  #table div{
      display:block;
      float:none;
  }

}
```

now at desktop or greater the 800px screen it should be display as table

like

```
1 2 3
```

and less then 800px screen width it should be display like this;

```
1
2
3
```

you are able to extend this media query as you required.
i hope your question is Answered.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get this type of output

```
1
2
3
```

you can add `style='float: left;width: 100%;'` for each TD tag.

Answer (score 0):

Does this achieve what you want?

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    td {
        display: block;
        clear:left;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/ak9qwx7p/) here.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?  http://jsfiddle.net/1w7arzmm/

```
td{
float:left;
display:block;
clear:left;
}
```